# Visual Studio doesn't recognise imported npm package?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015, npm

When importing npm packages into my project in Visual Studio, it always baffles me that sometimes, the packages just don't get recognised no matter how many times I refresh the folders.

[image]

The folder `react-google-maps` is definitely in my node_modules folder. However, for some reason, Visual Studio cannot see this error and highlights it as an error. And because of this, all relevant intellisense don't show up too. Strangely, it can actually recognise `react`!

What should I do to get Visual Studio to recognise new packages I just installed through npm in the console so that I can import them without the highlighted errors?

Comment: Unfortunately I had to switch to VS Code because VS is not supporting modern web development properly. `What should I do to get Visual Studio to ...` not much you can do.

Comment: @Rudy VS Code is great, but the intellisense in VS studio (even their community version which I'm using) surpasses the one in VS code. It feels a lot more responsive as I type my code. :(

Answer (score 0):

I beleive your issue is that `react-google-maps` is a JavaScript module. To let TypeScript import the module you need some typings translating JavaScript into TypeScript, e.g. from DefinitelyTyped repository.

A quick search found no such typings, why I'm assuming you didn't install any typings for this.

There are two solutions, if this is the case.

1. Write the typings and commit them to DefinitelyTyped or the Typings registry. This is the my recomended aproach. Give somthing back to the community by writing the typings and publishing it for others.
2. Declare a module in your project to silence the import. This one does not give you any IntelliSence, so it only silences the import.

To declare the module in your project, add a new file named `react-google-maps.d.ts` and paste this in:

```
declare module "react-google-maps" {
    export var GoogleMap;
    export var Marker;
}
```